# lisse sheaf on complex varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety, and let $F=(F_n)$ be a lisse $\mathbb Z_{\ell}$-sheaf on $X.$ Does there exist an analytic open covering of $X(\mathbb C),$ such that $F$ is "(locally) constant" on each open subset?

Comment: Lisse means smooth in french, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Lisse (French for smooth) is being used here as a technical term from the theory of etale sheaves.  It is usually left untranslated.  



Comment: By "analytic open subset" you mean an open set w.r.t. the good old Euclidean topology, or the complement of a closed analytic subvariety?

Comment: Presumably an injective local biholomorphism is an open embedding in this sense.

Comment: To "unknown (google)": I mean the "Euclidean top", like an open unit disk, not the "analytic Zariski top".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dear Shenghao, If you really do mean a lisse sheaf on the etale site of $X$, then it doesn't make sense a priori to evaluate it on analytic open subsets of $X(\mathbb C)$, since these are not in the etale site of the algebraic variety $X$.  However, $F$ corresponds to  a representation of the (profinite) etale $\pi_1$ of $X$, which in turn is the profinite completion of the
topological $\pi_1$ of $X(\mathbb C)$.  So there is a corresponding locally constant (in the analytic topology) $\mathbb Z_{\ell}$
sheaf on $X(\mathbb C)$, which, being locally constant, will be constant on sufficiently small analytic open subsets.

Comment: Without going through pi_1, you can just use the map of topoi X(C) --> X_et (induced by the pullback functor that sends U etale / X to the sheaf of sections of U(C) --> X(C) ).  This gives a pullback from lisse l-adic sheaves on X_et to lisse l-adic sheaves on X(C), all of which are indeed locally constant in the analytic topology, e.g. because a contractible open will canonically trivialize any Z/l^n-local system, and hence any lisee l-adic sheaf.

Comment: That's right, and is a more fundamental way to think about it.

Comment: Just by the way, what does the notation $X(\mathbb{C})$ mean?  The only thing I could think of was evaluation of the sheaf of sets $X$ on the affine scheme $\mathbb{C}$, but clearly that's not what's going on.  

Comment: There is a functor "associated analytic space" $X\mapsto X^{an}$ from schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ to complex analytic spaces. For a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $X$ the associated analytic space is a locally ringed space whose underlying set of point is just the set of closed points of $X$ that is $X(\mathbb{C})$. For example $(\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}})^{an}$ is $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the usual complex topology and the sheaf of holomorphic functions.  

Comment: If X is a scheme and S is another scheme, the notation X(S) is used to denote the set Hom(S,X), aka the S-points of X. (The idea of course is to identify a scheme with its functor of points.) If S = Spec R is affine, we just write X(R). 

Comment: The Hom(S,X) does not seem like it should be a scheme at all.  I wasn't aware that Sch had any notion of an internal hom.  I mean, we can define such an object in the category of _all_ sheaves of sets on a site, but it does not seem true that such a creature would be representable by affines.  

Comment: To Emerton: I think it does make sense, as explained by Dustin Clausen. I'm taking the analytification of the espace etale of the F_n's. I was worried about if the index of the kernel of the Z_l rep of the topological \pi_1 is finite or not (i.e. lisse or locally constant). Thank you for reminding me that, in the top setting, the correspondence between rep of top \pi_1 and LOCALLY CONSTANT sheaves doesn't involve the profinite topology of the top \pi_1 at all. 

To Dustin Clausen: thank you for reminding me that analytic spaces are locally contractible!

Comment: To Brian Conrad: it seems to me that Emerton and Clausen's answers prove the claim, without using alterations. Is the "clever short argument using alterations" for some more general claim? 

Comment: To shenghao:  The point of my communication with Deligne was a proof without local triangulizability of analytifications of complex algebraic schemes.  I wondered if one could use a cohomological method bypassing pi_1.  By way of motivation, there is a comparison theorem for Berkovich spaces with finite coefficients over non-arch field of *any* char., for which one cannot use resolution, and Berkovich gave a resolution-free proof (which adapts to C too). For the \ell-adic limit, Deligne's method applies nicely over non-arch fields of *any* char.  Might also be useful for stacks. 

Comment: @fpqc: Read Appendix B of Hartshorne.